# How to add knockout js binding to custom template

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, cart, knockoutjs

We want to add proceed to checkout button

on product detail page.

We will show this checkout button when cart have items

otherwise we will remove this.

See this : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1702035/4335f469aee99eb7375a9fdeb7d2f22e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got Solutions:

```
<div class="cart-section" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'" >
 <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>" class="checkout-btn"><?php echo __('Checkout'); ?></a>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

scope: 'minicart_content' will provide all scope 
values 
that is why `<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') --> is working`

Comment: We just need to define scope & then we will be able to use binding any where in magento 2

Answer (score 1):

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     require(['jquery', 
>             'yourjs'], function ($) {
>         (function () {
>         //write your code here 
>         })(jQuery);
>     }); </script>
```

you can use your require js parameters in **yourjs**
try this :)